# How to implement paging function in the datagrid when using data binding (winforms)?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, user-interface

I use data binding to control the datagrid, which connect to database table directly, what I want to do now is to implement the pager function on the datagrid, which I can only load 20 records from Database into memory, and display them.
What do I know now is the the data binding will load all the records into database and then do some filtering and display in the control..
any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicaly you have to run your datagrid in virtual mode, tell the grid how many rows there are in your recordset and then react to the CellValueNeeded-event. We implemented caching follwing [this example on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171624.aspx) .

Answer (score 1):

You need to load 20 records at a time in your data source, i.e. you have to implement paging yourself. Each time the user requests a new page, you read the new set of records.

On the SQL side, 'sql paging' will get you lots of results from your favorite search engine and [here is an example](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/070628.htm).